# Auto wrap lines in vim without inserting newlines

Tags: vim

How do set vim to wrap text without inserting newlines?

Basically:

- I want to have a max width, say 80 lines
- As I type out a paragraph, if a word passes the 80 line mark, it should wrap the entire word (no splitting the word)
- If I type more than a couple of lines, it should still be wrapping
- If I save the file, I shouldn't see any line breaks unless I explicitly hit Enter when typing in edit mode

I can get some of this behavior with:

```
:set textwidth=80
:set wrap
```

Except this will insert newlines, and I **don't** want it to insert newlines. I already tried [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it's very easy : reduce the width of your window to 80 characters.

Comment: To actually make this advice useful: keep in mind that you can create a split of required width by pressing `80 CTRL-W v` (or by typing `:80vsplit`.) Note that this is a total window width, so the actual text might be narrower due to `'number'`, `'relativenumber'`, `'foldcolumn'` and so on.

Comment: @romainl That would violate number two in that whole words would not be wrapped

Comment: @AlexanderBatischev Yeah that's what I've been doing, but it's a bit of a hack, no? It seems like there should be a better way

Comment: @gyeh, it's definitely a hack, but the requirement itself is quite unusual. Are you sure it's not an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? Can you explain *why* you need such a wrapping mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reducing the width of the window to circa 80 characters, `set wrap`, and `set linebreak` should satisfy all your requirements.

See `:help 'wrap'` and `:help 'linebreak'`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll accept your answer, but could you update your response to something like: `:set columns 120` `:set wrap` `:set linebreak`. That way it's easier for someone searching for this functionality to quickly try it to ensure that this is the right thing.

Answer (score 46):

If your goal, while typing in insert mode, is to automatically **soft-wrap text (only visually) at the edge of the window**:

```
set number # (optional - will help to visually verify that it's working)
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
set wrap
set linebreak # (optional - breaks by word rather than character)
```

---

If your goal, while typing insert mode, is to automatically **hard-wrap text (by inserting a new line into the actual text file) at 80 columns**:

```
set number # (optional - will help to visually verify that it's working)
set textwidth=80
set wrapmargin=0
set formatoptions+=t
set linebreak # (optional - breaks by word rather than character)
```

---

If your goal, while typing in insert mode, is to automatically **soft-wrap text (only visually) at 80 columns**:

```
set number # (optional - will help to visually verify that it's working)
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
set wrap
set linebreak # (optional - breaks by word rather than character)
set columns=80 # <<< THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
```

The latter took me 2-3 significant Internet-scouring sessions to find from here (give 'er a read - it's very well-written): https://agilesysadmin.net/how-to-manage-long-lines-in-vim/

Comment: Shouldn't that be `set number` instead of `set numbers`?

Comment: It's there two more times ;)

Comment: What the? Man, you'd think after all these years I'd be more observant than that - thanks again~

Answer (score 0):

In my case the line was far too long so I had to do `set display+=truncate`. Thanks @Friedrich, I'm going to add that to my vimrc

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: From what I can tell vim can't handle lines that are far too long and will just display empty lines starting with @, see https://i.imgur.com/qm5UBAD.png

Comment: I see. In that case `:set nowrap` and vertical scrolling can be used. I remember faintly there was a way to turn off the @ thing and just show as much as fits the screen.

Comment: Too good there's a site which has all the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060887/very-long-line-in-vim-does-not-show-up-without-having-the-cursor-on-it Your issue should be resolved with `:set display+=truncate`.

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich, I couldn't find it when I searched

Comment: hmmm `less` is still better, I can move one line at a time

Comment: That would be `gj` and `gk` ... but feel free to use `less`. It's a great tool, after all.

Comment: It's quite brittle, I prefer the arrow keys. Still a big fan of vim. Thanks for your help