# Very long line in VIM does not show up without having the cursor on it

Tags: vim, txt

I'm using VIM version `8.2`

When I'm on the line **above** the very long line, it appears as if there is no line below it. (Refer Below Image)

[image: Very long line disappears]

But as soon as I move down, I get to see everything in that line. (Refer Below Image)
[image: Very long line appears]

*Is there a way to make the very long line appear whithout having the cursor on it?*

Comment: See `:help 'display'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `set display+=truncate` or `set display+=lastline`, which tell Vim to display the last line but put `@@@` in the first or last column to indicate the rest is not displayed.

Also see https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Working_with_long_lines

Comment: Thanks, it works!
Just curious what "@@@" signifies in vim.

Comment: As `:h 'display'` mentions, it indicates the rest of the line is not displayed.